# mysql big query performance improvement

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone know how I can optimise this query? It works but it takes so long that it causes server timeouts when there's a heavy load.

```
$screenRestrict="clientID='1' AND screenID='1'";
$lastupdate="1318515710";

INSERT INTO allvisits (clientID, screenID, hitID, entryPageID, entryPageName, xentryTime, xexitTime, pagecount, minsonsite)(
    SELECT 
        clientID, screenID, id AS hitID, pageID AS entryPageID,
        (SELECT name FROM pages WHERE id=entryPageID) AS entryPageName,
        (SELECT clicktime FROM clicks WHERE id = hitID AND isFirstClick=1 ) AS xentryTime,
        (SELECT MIN(clicktime) FROM clicks WHERE $screenRestrict AND isLastClick=1 AND clicktime > xentryTime) AS xexitTime,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clicks WHERE $screenRestrict AND clicktime BETWEEN xentryTime AND xexitTime) AS pagecount,
        (SELECT (xexitTime-xentryTime)/60) AS minsonsite
    FROM clicks WHERE $screenRestrict AND isFirstClick=1 AND clicktime>'$lastupdate'
)
```

Thanks a lot :)

**Update:**

Thanks to all for the tips. I've added an index to isLastClick and managed to speed it up a good deal but it still takes +10 seconds on a low server load. I've identified the last bottleneck and marked it below. Is there any better way to select the first "isLastClick" record that is later than xentrytime?

```
SELECT clientid, 
             screenid, 
             id                                                      AS hitid, 
             pageid                                                  AS entrypageid, 
             clicktime                                               AS xentrytime, 
             (SELECT name 
                FROM   pages 
                WHERE  id = entrypageid)                               AS entrypagename, 
             (SELECT clicktime 
                FROM   clicks 
                WHERE  clicktime > xentrytime //<<removing this cuts 8.5 seconds!!
                             AND screenid = '2' 
                             AND islastclick = 1 
                             LIMIT 1)             AS xexittime, 
             (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                FROM   clicks 
                WHERE  screenid = '2' 
                             AND clicktime BETWEEN xentrytime AND xexittime) AS pagecount, 
             (SELECT ( xexittime - xentrytime ) / 60)                AS minsonsite 
FROM   clicks 
WHERE  screenid = '2' 
             AND isfirstclick = 1 
             AND clicktime > '1318961057'
```

Comment: firstly you should run `explain` for every of your select queries to understand where can be performance issue. and check indexes.

Comment: tried adding indexes to the columns you query on?

Comment: Cool didnt know about "explain" - I'll look at it. All the "ID" columns are primary keys. I dont think there's any other unique data in the clicks table so I'm not sure there's any way to add indexes?

Comment: [You might also want to add `LIMIT 1` to your subqueries that aren't using aggregate functions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455476/does-adding-limit-1-to-mysql-queries-make-them-faster-when-you-know-there-will)

Comment: do format your query when u post here. use sites like [this](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)

Comment: cronoklee, start with explain and then read about indexes.. it can increase your app performance dramatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check for comments.

if $screenrestrict and page id are same for a page. try to join the inner tables with that page id

I am not sure of your idea about xentrytime and xexittime columns. because, i see feilds fetched using sub query for the same thing.

Just remember, for tuning a query try to attain a filter and restrict the number of rows selected in each sub query. Some filters are written based on business logic, so think of including those condition also when u write a query, and see if performance improves in explain plan.

```
INSERT INTO allvisits 
            (clientid, 
             screenid, 
             hitid, 
             entrypageid, 
             entrypagename, 
             xentrytime, 
             xexittime, 
             pagecount, 
             minsonsite) 
(SELECT clientid, 
        screenid, 
        id                                                      AS hitid, 
        pageid                                                  AS entrypageid, 
        (SELECT name 
         FROM   pages 
         WHERE  id = entrypageid)                               AS entrypagename 
        , 
        clicktime                        AS xentrytime, //this should work w.r.t your code
        (SELECT MIN(clicktime)             //try to change this logic. The logic written here doesnt look good at all. and try to filter out data by joining with outer table. 
         FROM   clicks 
         WHERE  $screenrestrict 
                AND islastclick = 1 
                AND clicktime > xentrytime)                     AS xexittime, 
        (SELECT COUNT(1)   //this will give some performance improvement
         FROM   clicks 
         WHERE  $screenrestrict 
                AND clicktime BETWEEN xentrytime AND xexittime) AS pagecount, 
        (SELECT ( xexittime - xentrytime ) / 60)                AS minsonsite 
 FROM   clicks 
 WHERE  $screenrestrict 
        AND isfirstclick = 1 
        AND clicktime > '$lastupdate')
```

**Updated**

These 2 inner queries need some more of fine tuning

```
       SELECT MIN(innClick.clicktime)             
         FROM   clicks innClick1
         WHERE  innClick1.screenid =  '2' // when u put it as part of big query use  WHERE  innClick1.screenid = outClick.screenid instead of hard coding it. where outClick is alias for Click table in outside
                AND innClick1.islastclick = 1 
                AND innClick1.clicktime > innClick1.xentrytime

        SELECT COUNT(1) 
         FROM   clicks innClick2
         WHERE  innClick2.screenid =  '2' 
                AND innClick2.clicktime BETWEEN innClick2.xentrytime AND innClick2.xexittime
```

w.r.t explain plan

- You can try to add more filter to reduce number of rows fetched in inner query.
- try to reduce any full table scan, and if the scan is based on index scan (full also) can be ignored for time being.
- try to add filters based on the columns that are already indexed.
- try to do a lot of trial and error by filtering data further in these sub-queries and  -
- try to reduce the time in each query separately. and then finally join them when u have a better performance

The clicktime, xentrytime and xexittime if indexed will yeild better performance for the query i guess. you can try it , `but still indexing will slow your insert statements` as those extra index should be updated each time an insert happen.

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot Babu! I've posted an update with your tips. How might I go about joining to the outer table and maintain accurate results?