# Does using "LIMIT 1" speed up a query on a primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a primary key of say `id` and I do a simple query for the key such as,

```
SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE id = X
```

Will it find one row and then stop looking as it is a primary key, or would it be better to tell mysql to limit its select by using `LIMIT 1`? For instance:

```
SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE id = X LIMIT 1
```

Comment: How can I try it?? It will always return just 1 row, I want to know if it stops doing a full table scan after finding the primary key!

Comment: @cgweb87: Please confirm that my edit to your question makes it clearer, and not further from your intent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does using “LIMIT 1” speed up a query on a primary key?

No. It's already as fast as can be without `LIMIT 1`. `LIMIT 1` is effectively implied anyway.

> Will it find one row and then stop looking as it is a primary key

Yes.

No table scan should be necessary at all here: it's a key-based lookup. The matching row is found and that's the end of the procedure.

Comment: Does using “LIMIT 1” speed up a query on a primary key? Yes or No. your answer suggests "no" but says "yes".

Comment: @TarranJones: I don't understand why you think it suggests "no".

Comment: I made the assumption that a key based lookup would be "SELECT primary_key_id FROM myTable WHERE primary_key_id = X". ( no "limit 1") correct ? so if using a key-based lookup means the procedure ends as soon as it finds a matching row. Then the answer is No. adding limit 1 does not speed up a query on a primary key.

Comment: @TarranJones: Hmm, yes. Looks like I missed a few factors of the question at the time.

Comment: @cgweb87: You should unaccept this answer; it's not right.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I didn't touch the question title.

Comment: I am very sorry to have said you did - my saying that came across as an accusation. I misread the edit history - your name was just below the edit that changed the title, but you did a different edit. I will delete my comment, and submit a corrected one.

Comment: The confusion as to whether this answer is saying Yes or No is due to the question's title having been edited to say the opposite of the essential sentence "Will it find one row and then stop looking as it is a primary key," Lightness is saying `Yes`, it will stop even w/o LIMIT statement; a primary key is guaranteed to be unique; the query optimizer doesn't have to scan the table. Which means `No`, it won't be faster if you add LIMIT statement.

Comment: @TarranJones There

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to worry about this sort of "optimization".

Only one row will be fetched -- per unique index contract -- and the database is able to *very quickly* find all the (1) rows. It is able to do this because of the underlying structures that back the index (or primary key) support fast-seeking by value. There is no table-scan involved. (Generally a variant of a B-tree, but it might be hash-based, etc, is used. I suppose a smart query optimizer might also be able to pass down additional hints based on the unique constraint in effect, but I don't know enough about this.)

Comment: Thanks, my database has over 500,000 rows with unique keys and was just going to try it to speed up performance a bit.

Comment: @cgweb87 You can always run a test. I suspect "no change", but if you discover a noticeable difference, then 1) profit 2) write follow-up SO question 3) more profit :)

Comment: @cgweb87 Don't forget to analyze the query plans, as well as measuring wall-clock time.

Comment: I know a database that allows you to choose between B-tree or hash-based primary keys, although it does mean you have to explicitly index the key column before you're allowed to insert data into the table.

Comment: @Neil I have yet to use a database that does not use such for a primary key -- since one of the requirements for a primary key is uniqueness, it seems silly to do otherwise. Although, I have not used many databases :)