# How to Check if value exists in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, exists

Suppose I have this table:

```
id | name | city
------------------
1  | n1   | c1
2  | n2   | c2
3  | n3   | c3
4  | n4   | c4
```

I want to check if the value `c7` exists under the variable `city` or not.

If it does, I will do something.
If it doesn't, I will do something else.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

using modern MySQLi:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(SERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS, DATABASE);

$city = 'c7';
$result = $mysqli->execute_query("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE city = ? LIMIT 1", [$city]);
if($result->num_rows == 1) {
    // found
}
```

using legacy mysqli

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(SERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS, DATABASE);

$city = 'c7';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE city = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows == 1) {
    // found
}
```

using PDO:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);

$city = 'c7';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE city = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute([$city]);
if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
    // found
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use SQL's EXISTS statement like http://stackoverflow.com/a/1676573/204634 ?

Comment: Speed-wise, would it be faster by adding `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @IanY. that depends on the query but usually yes. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455476/does-adding-limit-1-to-mysql-queries-make-them-faster-when-you-know-there-will

Answer (score 18):

#### For Exact Match

```
"SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE city = 'c7'"
```

#### For Pattern / Wildcard Search

```
"SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE city LIKE '%c7%'"
```

Of course you can change `'%c7%'` to `'%c7'` or `'c7%'` depending on how you want to search it. For exact match, use first query example.

#### PHP

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE city = 'c7'");
$matchFound = mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ? 'yes' : 'no';
echo $matchFound;
```

You can also use `if` condition there.

Comment: Use id instead of * (star). And `PDO` or `MYSQLi` should be used.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me :

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'UserName', 'Password', 'DB_Name') or die('Not Connected');
mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8');

$sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE city='c7'");
$sql = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$Checker = $sql['city'];

if  ($Checker != null) {
    
    echo 'Already exists';
    
} else {

    echo 'Not found';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
select count(city) from mytable where city = 'c7'
```

This will send only a single value from the query. If it is 0 it is not present else it is present. Since you will not be use the other column values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    IF city='C7'
    THEN city
    ELSE 'somethingelse'
    END as `city`
FROM `table` WHERE `city` = 'c7'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to d this for a while and 
    `$sqlcommand = 'SELECT * FROM database WHERE search="'.$searchString.'";';

    $sth = $db->prepare($sqlcommand);
    $sth->execute();
    $record = $sth->fetch();
    if ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0){}`
just works if there are TWO identical entries, but, 
if you replace 
    `if ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0){}`
with
    `if ($result){}`
it works with only one matching record, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the connection is established and is available in global scope;

```
//Check if a value exists in a table
function record_exists ($table, $column, $value) {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$column} = {$value}";
    $result = mysql_query ( $query, $connection );
    if ( mysql_num_rows ( $result ) ) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Usage:
Assuming that the value to be checked is stored in the variable $username;

```
if (record_exists ( 'employee', 'username', $username )){
    echo "Username is not available. Try something else.";
} else {
    echo "Username is available";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**For Matching the ID:**

```
Select * from table_name where 1=1
```

**For Matching the Pattern:**

```
Select * from table_name column_name Like '%string%'
```

Answer (score -1):

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM   WHERE  = ''";
$found = mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ? 'Yes' : 'no' ;
echo $found;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here's is what worked with me if you're using PHP Version 8

```
$result = mysqli_query(database name, "SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE city = 'c7'");      
  
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       // Do Something 
  }
  else {
      // Do something else 
  }
```

The difference with my answer and Reindeer Wit is the **'i'** in **mysqli_query** and **mysqli_num_rows()**

Also including the name of the **database name** inside of **mysqli_query()** that you are using.

Comment: "I figured that Reinder Wit answer is a bit outdated" — It isn't. It has two sections. The first section is marked **preferred** and is supported from PHP 5 onwards. You were trying to follow the section marked **deprecated** which is **not** supported since PHP 7.