# PHP check if value exists in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to copy [How to Check if value exists in a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292468/check-if-value-exists-in-mysql) and make my own, but for some reason it wont work...

This is what I got:

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'multiplayer';
$con=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

$check_player_ip=mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT `player_ip` FROM `playerdata` WHERE username = "remco" AND active = 0');
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check_player_ip) == 0) {
      //didnt find anything
    } else{
      //found something
    }
?>
```

I get this error:
*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$check_player_ip' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 1*

**Solution**

If you get the T_VARIABLE error, check the varriable before this rule. You may forgot the place the ';' xD

Thanks for all support!

Comment: You have an error (extra i) : **mysqli_query** should be **mysql_query**

Comment: @Arkni Absolutely not. Rather `mysql_crap` should *at least* be `mysqli_crap`. Suggestions to the contrary ought to be posted a decade ago.

Comment: @user2864740 ,So in this case he should add the connection instance as first parameter(Edit: he edited his question).

Comment: @Arkni Ah, now we're getting somewhere :D

Comment: @user2864740 Edited connection to it for your wishes :)

Comment: @Remco If you're going to change your question at every 2 mins. with updates from answers given, I will vote to close. **DON'T DO THAT**. Leave your original question as is, and place comments under answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'multiplayer';

$con = new mysqli( $host, $username, $password, $dbname );

/* Check Connection */
    if ( $con->connect_error ) {
        printf( "Connect failed: %s\n", $con->connect_error );
        exit();
    }

/* Query - Returns a resultset */
    if ( $result = $con->query('SELECT `player_ip` FROM `playerdata` WHERE username = "remco" AND active = 0 ') ) {

    if ( $result->num_rows <= 0 ) {
      //didnt find anything
          printf("No player");
    } else {
      //found something
          printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
    }

    /* free result set */
        $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
    $con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Great
Vote the post then ;)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for it.... I am just (how the most ..... here on stackoverflow call me) a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You are mixing MySQL APIs, they do not mix together. `mysql_num_rows`</strike>

Use `mysqli_num_rows()`

Also make sure your DB connection is also `mysqli_*` and not `mysql_*`

**EDIT** after you've edited your question.

You need to pass DB connection to your query:

```
$check_player_ip=mysqli_query($con,'SELECT...`
```

`$con` being your DB connection. Change accordingly.

Plus `WHERE username = remco` - the word `remco` needs to be wrapped in quotes, it's a string and not an `int`.

`WHERE username = 'remco'`

---

***Sidenote:***

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

***Edit 2:***

Try inverting the quotes:

```
$check_player_ip=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `player_ip` FROM `playerdata` WHERE username = 'remco' AND active = 0");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check_player_ip) == 0) {
      //didnt find anything
    }
```

Comment: I've edited the code again and this time with "remco", still the same error :/

Comment: @Remco Reload my answer under Edit #2

Comment: I still get the T_VARIABLE error :/

Comment: @Remco Is `username` column a VARCHAR and is `active` an `int`?

Comment: I got the problem, I've forget a ; to place after a variable! Thank you for helping me. Would you maybe upvote my question so I can ask tomorrow more questions on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Remco You're welcome and sure. Accept my answer though ;) because the initial problem was solved.

Comment: @Remco I take it you're not going to accept my answer then.

Comment: @Remco By the way, asking to upvote a question, isn't something that should be asked on Stack. You plan on coming back tomorrow to ask another question. I guess we know ahead of time that you're going to have problems. This isn't a "teach me how to code" or a "tutorial site", it's a site built by professionals "for" professionals. I will not exchange votes with you for mere points. What you posted in your question did **not** and was not the original cause, but something you did not show us from the start. Don't expect further help from me. Learn how to code and debug, it's your job, not ours.

Comment: As what you're saying is that this is a site build for professionals.... Am I then the only one who's a beginner on the whole site? Or are they already banned from this 'community'?

Comment: @Remco 90% of the time, people who are new to Stack, don't bother reading or taking the tour **http://stackoverflow.com/tour** and to understand/comprehend how to ask a question, the steps they've taken to figure out why their code isn't working, nor spending enough time to debug their code. More often than none, people give up too easily after spending no more than 10 minutes on Google 30 at the most, then immediately resort to the guys on Stack to figure out their problem **right away**. That is not how it works. Stack put the site together, I didn't. There's a certain etiquette to follow.

Comment: Well I've been searching for a solution for like 1,5 hour... I've readed the code serveral times but I just couldn't found the error. So thats when I thought to post this here. And about the upvote thing.... Thats only because IF I have another problem what I just cannot figure out, then I hope that I can ask that question here and not somewhere else...

Comment: @Remco Word of advice; be honest with people. If you include something to that effect in a question stating that you've spent many hours trying to fix it yourself, or that you don't know what to look for, people will genuinely want to help. When you are not honest and this being "leaving out parts of your code", then people will shy away and won't help you. Even though this is the Internet, there are actual "people" behind the screen, just like you, remember that ;) P.s.: You may not do this yourself, but I've spent up to **3 days** on a few occasions, in trying to solve a code problem.

Comment: @Remco Plus, don't alter code in your original question, that is a no-no. Instead, post comments under the person's answer stating that it is not working, including errors/warnings you may get in trying to use that person's answer. Something you may have tried can be made as an **Edit** and written as such, stating it is an "edit", under the original question. I'm trying to help you out here, so I hope you appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

you should execute that mysqli query...

```
while($rows = mysql_arrayAssoc($ursql)){
    $data[]=$rows;
}
if($something== $data['attribute']) //attribute(id,name...)
    echo "ok some data is in"
else 
   echo "no matching data"
```

I hope it help you :)

Comment: That doesn't help at all :) But thank you for responding.

Comment: oh ye, and ofcourse you have to setup connection do your database, didn't check well at start of php :p

Comment: I've edited the connection to the code for your wishes :) Maybe could you help me now? Or do you want to see the hole database also? :D

Comment: 1st check if your connection is ok                               `if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }`                                                               then in if clause `if(false===$check_player_ip)` {echo "error"}       I suggest you do go debug slowly step by step...and read some documentation for MYSQLI     http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: That works fine, because otherwise my hole code wont work :) I just cut this piece of the code out of the hole part. Connection is not the problem, T_VARIABLE error is the problem.

Comment: Ffs, I got the problem, I've forget a ; to place after a variable! Thank you for helping me. Would you maybe upvote my question so I can ask tomorrow more questions on stackoverflow? :)