# how to check whether the date comes from a form is the same as the date stored in mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql, date, validation

I have a MySQL database table called "booking" and fileds called "arrival" and "diparture".

| arrival | diparture |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-22 | 2022-03-23 |

now I want to check whether a random date is present within these two dates(date in the database).
I want it to be done in PHP.

I don't know the easy way to do it.

Comment: You need to write PHP code for it. What have you written so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Check if value exists in a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292468/how-to-check-if-value-exists-in-a-mysql-database)

Comment: Question little bit not clear. Do you want to check a random date equal to one of the given dates?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateChecked = '2022-03-20' ;
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE arrival <= :dateChecked AND diparture >= :dateChecked";
$dateStatement = $mysqlClient->prepare($sqlQuery);
$dateStatement->execute(['dateChecked' => $dateChecked]);
$dates = $recipesStatement->fetch();
        
if ($dates)
    return true ;
        else
   return false ;
```