# Delete email from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got to delete about 10 email addresses from a huge database, wanted to find out the correct way to delete multiple emails from the db at once. I can delete one by one, just wondered if it was separating them by commas which I now need.

I presumed this is the appropriate SQL Statement:

```
DELETE FROM `subscribers` 
WHERE email='example1@example.com,example2@example.com,example3@example.com'
```

Is this the correct way to list multiple emails in order for them to be deleted from the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IN()` and put the emails in quotes

```
DELETE FROM `subscribers` 
WHERE email IN('example1@example.com','example2@example.com','example3@example.com')
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Will accept the answer later as I cannot for 15 minutes.

Comment: Append a `LIMIT 3` to be totally awesome. :)

Comment: @CodeAngry: That does not improve anything.

Comment: @juergend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455476/does-adding-limit-1-to-mysql-queries-make-them-faster-when-you-know-there-will

Comment: @CodeAngry: That may work for selects. Has to be tested for deletes and how do you know there are no duplicate emails? Then adding a limit will not delete all.

Comment: @juergend There shouldn't be in the `subscribers` table. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `=`, use `IN`.  E.g.

```
DELETE FROM subscribers 

WHERE email IN ('example1@example.com','example2@example.com','example3@example.com')
```